# How to recombine html5 Animate-CC Publishes (because the file was too big before)?

Tags: javascript, easeljs, animate-cc

I have an html5 canvas project that's made to function as a multi-page eLearning interaction. Each "page" is designed to be a movieclip set on a main timeline, and buttons (page indicators) just use `gotoAndPlay();` to get to the right page.

I ran into an issue after making it 5 pages long where Animate CC would say it was "Out of Memory" and couldn't export anything because the file was too big.

It seems like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901564/two-flash-cc-animations-in-the-same-html-page#) is on the right track, but I was trying to see **if there'd be a way to divide each page into a separate `.FLA` file, and then combine them after?**

I'd provide a link, but I can't publish it...

There's an intro page, then 3 scenarios the user has to go through. These should auto advance, but should be accessible from the other pages.

To further complicate it, the last page (conclusion/review) is supposed to link back to each of the three scenarios, shown here:
[image: conclusion page screenshot]

At this point, I'm not even sure if it's possible to get it to work how I want. It would have been nice if Animate CC could've just published it out, and I wouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there are no duplicate names, you should be able to just load all the libs at once. The export format is built so it is additive -- so it will use existing `lib`, `images`, and `ss` references to combine all the lib elements into one global library.

You should be able to confirm this, and then combine/minify all the files together if it works.

Comment: Sounds simple enough! I'll probably want to make sure that I leave the image spritesheet box unchecked, correct? And then combine all the javascript where it would go as if I exported it in one file?

Comment: In theory, yeah it should. I am not 100% sure about the manifest, as I think it might get defined on each library -- that could definitely cause some problems, as some images may not get loaded... Worth testing.

Comment: Ok, so I've tested the separate files, and it's ready to combine. the libs are additive, and I can combine the resource files, but what do I need to worry about on the html files, exactly?